# show loading div for dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

here below is my code, i have a loading div named `dvLoading`, can anyone tell me where or how I would show the loading div in the open attribute and hide it when opened?

```
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Add',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: height,
                width: width,
                /*show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },*/
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do ? Show a loading div in a dialog when something is loading ? Or Show a loading div until the dialog is open ?

Comment: the dialog opens instantly, put the page in the open: $this.load(url) loads quite slowly, i want to show the loading div inside the dialog until its open...
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. (Not tested)
according to the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation.

```
$("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Add',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: height,
            width: width,
            /*show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },*/
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            //This function is launched when your dialog open.
            open: function (event, ui) {
                //Show the loading div on open.
                $("#dvLoading").show();
                //adding a callback function wich will be launched after the loading
                $(this).load(url,function(response, status, xhr) {
                                     if (status == "error") {
                                          var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                                          $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                                     } else $.("#dvLoading").hide();
                                 });
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });
```